# Passing variables through activities

Tags: android

I'm making an apps and I need to pass variables between two different activites. I got a TextEdit, in which I save the entry to pass it to another activity. Here's my code :

Activity "textEdit" (let call it like this...) :

```
if (editText_descriptionHomework.getText().toString().matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messErr_noInput, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    String descr = editText_descriptionHomework.getText().toString();
                    i.putExtra(description, descr);

                    finish();

                    startActivity(i);

                }
```

And here's the "main activity" (in which I want to display this data) :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("description");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

So, if I put nothing, I correctly have the toast saying "error blablabl", but if I put something, and I click on the button which trigg the "textEdit activity" code, it display nothing (black toast with no caracters).

Did I write something wrong guys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
i.putExtra("description", descr);
```

Yours doesn't have the quotes...

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this

```
i.putString("description", descr);
```

you forgot the quotes

Answer (score 1):

first it is better to replace this :

```
if (editText_descriptionHomework.getText().toString().matches(""))
```

by

```
if (editText_descriptionHomework.getText().toString().idEmpty())
```

that way you are making sure the EditText is empty, .match is like preg_match but for android
Now to get the value, try this instead:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtrasString("description");
```

or

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
```

Last replace :

```
i.putExtra(description, descr);
```

by

```
i.putExtra("description",descr);
```